# What does bind and unbind mean in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding

What does bind and unbind mean in jquery in idiot slow learner terms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Binding: coupling an **handler** to an **element**(s), that will run when an **event** occurs on said element(s). Depending on what kind of event you want to handle you'd use different functions like `click(function)` (alt: `bind('click', function)` or `focus(function)` (alt: `bind('focus', function)`.

Unbinding: de-coupling of an **handler** from an **element(s)**, so that when an **event** occurs the handler function will no longer run. Unbinding is always the same; `unbind('click', function)` to unbind a certain handler, `unbind('click')` to unbind ALL click handlers, and `unbind()` to unbind ALL handlers. You can substitute `click` for other types of events of course.

Answer (score 7):

In simple terms: for [binding](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind) and [unbinding](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/unbind) event handlers to elements.

```
$("#divElement").bind('click', functionName);
```

binds a click event handler to the element with id divElement

```
$("#divElement").unbind('click', functionName);
```

unbinds a click event handler to the element with id divElement

Edit:

**Bind also allows you to bind a handler to one or more events.**

```
$("#divElement").bind("click dblclick mouseout", function(){ // your code });
```

Update:

As of jQuery 1.7, the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements.

Comment: Might want to include the fact that you can bind a handler to multiple events in one bind command

Comment: Also might want to add that you can bind to arbitrary event names like `$("div").bind("updatePage", function() {...});` then trigger those events with $("div").trigger("updatePage");

Comment: This article - http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/03/26/special-events is a good introduction to special events

Answer (score 3):

In three sentences:

An **event** is a signal that is visible in your program - a key press, for example.

A **handler** is a function that is geared towards reacting to a certain event.

**Binding** associates a handler with an event, **unbinding** does the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Bind attaches a piece of code to be run to a given HTML element (which is run on the supplied event).  unbind removes it.