# Use of Binding after Unbinding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I found a code as shown below.

Html code:

```
<div id="myButton">Click Here</div>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$("#myButton").unbind("click").bind("click",function(){
   alert("Working")
});
```

What is the need of **unbind("click")** before binding the element?

It is also working if unbind is not used. like shown below

```
$("#myButton").bind("click",function(){
   alert("Working")
});
```

Which one is best? what is the difference?

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264353/what-does-bind-and-unbind-mean-in-jquery

Comment: As of jQuery1.7 [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) is recommended. Your code will be `$("#myButton").off().on()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only makes sure, that there is no other `click` event listener attached. So your handler will be the only handler acting upon clicking the `#myButton`

**Edit:** as @T.J. Crowder noted in the comments, `unbind()` will not affect handlers attached in different way than by calling `bind()`.

It is also worth noting, that:

> as of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements

(excerpt from the [jQuery.unbind() doc](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)). In fact, `unbind()` [is implemented internally](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event/alias.js#L26) by the `off()` method).

Consider:

```
$("#myButton").bind('click', function () {
  console.log('click 1');
});

$("#myButton").unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
  console.log('click 2');
});

// When clicked, prints "click 2"
```

Versus:

```
$("#myButton").bind('click', function () {
  console.log('click 1');
});

// note: no unbind here
$("#myButton").bind('click', function () {
  console.log('click 2');
});

// When clicked, prints "clicked 1" followed by "clicked 2"
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this will only unbind handlers attached with *jQuery*. It won't unbind ones attached with an `onclick` attribute, the `onclick` property, or `addEventListener`. It also doesn't affect delegated handlers that match the button.

Answer (score 0):

By unbinding "click" event on an element, you are actually removing all the onclick events associated with that element. i.e. if your html form's input field has an onclick event and it calls a function, it will be unbound. After an unbind, you are binding another click event which will call your function onclick of that element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myButton").unbind("click").bind("click",function(){
   alert("Working")
});
```

jQuery bind() function is used to attach an event handler to elements, while the unbind() is used to detached an existing event handler from elements. please see a demo http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/jQuery/jQuery-bind-unbind-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Without url of this html code , i'm not sure that `#myButton`element whether has other `click` handler attached ,but what is certain is `unbind` method remove all the handler on this element , i think the author only want to trigger one click event.
Also, you can see if there is other event handler on debug inspector of browser.
Hope this will help you.